# how to make php page available only on some pre defined IP addresses?

Tags: php

I am writing a script in code ignitor and I would like to make some pages which availables to only some ip range. if some one else out of that range will open it will be redirected to the pre defined page. I am looking for the solution to this in code ignitor. kindly help me out with this please.

Comment: Darshak, have a look at my answer and please tell if it is good or not. `:)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a simple IP Address finding script like:

```
// Function to get the client IP address
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

And make a choice like:

```
$whitelistedIPAddresses = array("127.0.0.1", "192.168.0.1");
if (!in_array(get_client_ip(), $whitelistedIPAddresses))
  exit;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. +1 for Quick Draw McGraw.